# What's wrong with NSIS shortcut?

Tags: json, exe, nsis, shortcut

Should warning, that english is not my native, sorry for grammar misstakes.

I have a problem with shortcut that i create with NSIS. The shortcut's link leads to exe file, that use a json config, config is in the same directory with exe, and when i use the shortcut it returns me an error, that it can't finde the config, cause it's searching in the shortcut's directory. But when i make the shortcut by myself it works correct - searching config in the exe's directory. I need to create the shortcut, that will uses a config which lies in instdir. How to make it correctly?

That's how i create the shortcut:

```
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\%link_name%.lnk" \
"$INSTDIR\%SomeDir%\Application.exe" \
"" \
"C:\Users\Daniil.Bogdanov\Pic\logo.ico" 0
```

The config and exe lie in %SomeDir%

Comment: Your application should not depend on the working directory, this is a bug you need to fix.

Comment: It doesn't depend from directory. I think. But i may be wrong. Can you explain where is the error, please?

Comment: In your app you must access the config file with a full path.

Comment: Oh, yea, you're right, but it is another story :D

Comment: No it is not another story. A shortcut is not the only way a user can start your application with a different working directory.

Comment: If I undertstand you right (sorry for dum questions), you mean, that my exe shouldn't find the config in the same directory where it was start, and that the path to config shouldn't be relative. I understand that, but it is not my part of the app and i can't fix it. So, honestly, i even don't undesrtand how it work that app can starts from other directory by shortcut or something, i thought that it always starts from it's place

Comment: The working directory has nothing to do with where the exe lives, the working directory is used to resolve relative paths. If a user does "open with" on a file in Explorer a chooses your app the working directory will probably be where that Explorer window is currently. Or in cmd.exe: `c:\full\path\app.exe ..\file.txt`

Comment: I get it now, great thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most intuitive thing but CreateShortCut sets the working directory for your shortcut based on the current `$OUTDIR` value.

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#createshortcut

> $OUTDIR is stored as the shortcut's working directory property. You can change it by using SetOutPath before creating the shortcut

So I'm guessing that your output path isn't the same as the location of your executable. This could be remedied by using `SetOutputPath` right before creating your shortcut.

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\%SomeDir%\"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\%link_name%.lnk" \
"$INSTDIR\%SomeDir%\Application.exe" \
"" \
"C:\Users\Daniil.Bogdanov\Pic\logo.ico" 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, NSIS has only eng documentation, so i lost some part of sense